# SQLite: which character can be ignored with FTS match in one word

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, match

I need to find any special character.  If I put it in the middle of a word, SQLite FTS match can ignore it as if it does not exist, e.g.:

```
Text Body: book's
```

If my match string is 'books' I need to get result of "book's"..
No problem using porter or simple tokenizer.

I tried many characters for that like: book!s, book?s, book|s, book,s, book:s…, but when searching by match for 'books' no results of these returned.

I don't understand, why?

I am using: Contentless FTS4 Tables, and External Content FTS4 Tables, my text body has many characters in each word, should be changed to ignore it when searching..

I cannot change match query because I do not know where the special character in the word is.  Also, I need to leave the original word length equal to the length of FTS Index word to use match info or snippet(); as such, I cannot remove these characters from text body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default tokenizers do not ignore punctuation characters but treat them as word separators.

So the text body or match string `book's` will end up as two words, `book` and `s`.
These will never match a single work like `books`.

To ignore characters like `'`, you have to [install your own custom tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_8_1).

Comment: I am using 'System.Data.SQLite' from .net, so can I write custom tokenizer from C#? I do not know anything about  C or C++, so what to do?
Another way can I overwrite MATCH function as SQLite function from C# like REGEXP function?

Comment: `MATCH` already is a custom function, implemented by the FTS virtual table. You'll have to learn C, or hire someone who is competent.

Comment: Thank you.. Another two things, 1: is there any way to use regular expression with FTS or MATCH? 2: is this right way to hack SQLite tokenizer and if it's ok, how to that to solve my problem? see: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/FTS-simple-tokenizer-with-custom-delimeters-td43926.html

Comment: No. No (you want to ignore, not to delimit). (And question don't belong into comments.)